# Wie alt ist die Phrase „Achtung, fertig, los!“?

Tags: phrase, etymology

Wie alt ist die Phrase „Achtung, fertig, los!“?

Und gab es früher auch andere Phrasen dafür?

Ich finde es erstaunlich, dass sich hier eine Phrase so durchgesetzt hat, da das ja ähnlich wie Abzählreime auch bei Kinderspielen verwendet wird.

Comment: "Auf die Plätze, fertig, los"?

Comment: OregonGhost deutete es schon an - ich nehme an, dass die Vereinheitlichung von Sport-Reglements (moderne Olypmiaden) ihren Teil dazu beigetragen haben, auch entsprechende Phrasen oder Begriffe zu standardisieren. Z.B. schreiben die internationalen Wettkampfregeln der Leichtathleten in Regel 56 den Wortlaut des Startkommandos vor.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ich tappe auch im Dunkeln, aber ich habe in einem [Buch aus dem Jahr 1896 über Duelle](http://books.google.com/books?id=HsY_AAAAYAAJ&q=%22fertig%20los%22&dq=%22fertig%20los%22&hl=en&ei=XLwKToGiAtDs-gaDy-jOAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBTgK)  eine Textstelle gefunden, die darauf hindeuten könnte, wo der Ursprung des Kommandos liegt:

> Vorwärts streckten die Paukanten, Kreuzten in der Mitte beide Dann die Klingen, „Fertig! Los!" Also schallte das Commando.

(Duellbuch: Geschichte des Zweikampfes nebst einem Anhang enthaltend Duellregeln und Paukcomment von Hans Kufahl und Josef Schmied-Kowarzik).

Man findet in Büchern um 1860 auch die Wendung: „Auf die [Mensur](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mensur)! [Gebunden!] Fertig! Los!“ wie sie auch auf dieser alten Postkarte zu lesen ist:

[image: Auf die Mensur! Fertig! Los!]

Vielleicht kann jemand mit der Information etwas anfangen oder weiterforschen.

---

*Ein kleiner Exkurs:* Ich bin kein Fan von Studentenverbindungen und deren Ritualen, aber [der folgende Abschnitt im Wikipediaartikel zu Mensur](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mensur_%28Studentenverbindung%29#Einfluss_auf_die_moderne_Umgangssprache) könnte hier von allgemeinem Interesse sein.

> Im 19. Jahrhundert sind einige Fachbegriffe des studentischen Fechtens als bildliche Ausdrücke in die deutsche Alltagssprache eingedrungen, darunter:
>
> - etwas „auf Anhieb“ verstehen oder können: Der „Anhieb“ ist beim Mensurfechten der erste Hieb eines Ganges nach dem Kommando „Los“ der Sekundanten.
> - jemandem „eine Abfuhr erteilen“: Beim Mensurfechten wird derjenige, der eine so große Verletzung davongetragen hat, dass der Paukarzt die Partie beenden lässt, von den Vertretern seiner Verbindung „abgeführt“. Die Mensur wird damit einseitig für beendet erklärt. Der Gegenpaukant hat dem Abgeführten dann eine „Abfuhr erteilt“.
> - „einen Anschiss kassieren“: 1800 bis 1850 war ein „Anschiss“ eine Wunde, die mindestens einen Zoll lang war, klaffte und aus der mindestens ein Tropfen Blut floss. Wer einen „Anschiss kassiert“ hatte, wurde abgeführt.
> - „Pauken“ („intensiv lernen“): Mit „Pauken“ bezeichnet man bei schlagenden Verbindungen das Einüben des studentischen Fechtens zur Vorbereitung auf die Mensur, in der Regel im Rahmen der „Paukstunde“. Früher bezeichnete man damit auch das Fechten mit scharfen Waffen nach Einführung des Hiebfechtens und nach Abschaffung des Stoßfechtens. Später wurde der Begriff auf das Üben eingeengt und danach auf Lernen allgemein erweitert.

Comment: Hier wäre interessant zu wissen, ob und inwieweit in diesem Bereich ältere oder zeitgenössische militärische Exerzierregeln rezipiert wurden.

Comment: +1 allein schon für die Erklärung der Redewendungen "auf Anhieb", "eine Abfuhr erteilen" und "einen Anschiss kassieren".